# why is viewWillAppear called after the viewController is popped?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

After a user clicks the back button from the top left corner ( system provides ), 
the parent `ViewController's` `ViewWillAppear` is called which is right.

But the child ( the one is being popped ) is also called!!!! ( `ViewWillDisappear` is called before these two calls ) This doesn't make sense, when/why does this happen?

This happens after user made a few interactions in the child `ViewController`.

Call stack:

```
#0  0x003a48c6 in -[MyViewController viewWillAppear:] at MyViewController.mm:103
#1  0x324386fe in -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] ()
#2  0x32429ea8 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] ()
#3  0x3241c7e8 in __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke ()
#4  0x3241c718 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] ()
#5  0x3241c808 in __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke ()
#6  0x3241c718 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] ()
#7  0x3241c808 in __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke ()
#8  0x3241c718 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] ()
#9  0x3242968a in -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] ()
#10 0x324294de in -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] ()
#11 0x3250add6 in -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] ()
#12 0x3250a9e4 in -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:] ()
#13 0x3250a44a in __101-[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:]_block_invoke_2 ()
#14 0x3249d6f4 in _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack ()
#15 0x3241655a in _afterCACommitHandler ()
#16 0x2fbcd2a4 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#17 0x2fbcac48 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#18 0x2fbcaf8a in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#19 0x2fb35f0e in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#20 0x2fb35cf2 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#21 0x34a57662 in GSEventRunModal ()
#22 0x3248116c in UIApplicationMain ()
#23 0x000cac10 in main
```

Comment: Try to use `NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__)` to verify which one is calling `viewWillApear`.

Comment: callstack is attached.